# To highlight one point in Violin chart PlotlyJS

Tags: javascript, styles, plotly, plotly.js, violin-plot

I am using Violin chart of PlotylyJS library, and it takes an array of elements and plots it on the chart. Is possible if I want to highlight one point with a different color from that array?

Like if my array is

```
demoViolin = [31.8, 63.5, 65, 59, 71, 72, 79, 68, 66, 89, 71, 67, 77]
```

I want to plot this on the graph but I want the point 65 to be highlighted with a different color.

Comment: hey did you ever figure out a solution for this? thanks

Comment: no, couldn't figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this could be Insight of your issue.

You can use `selectedpoints` with `selected` for highlighting.

```
var data = [{  
    //https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/violin/#violin-selectedpoints
    selectedpoints: [2],
    selected : {
        marker :{
            color: 'rgb(255,0,0)'
        }
    },
    //jitter: 0, //If needed points align same x-axis
    type: 'violin',
    y: demoViolin, 
    points: 'all',  
    box: {
        visible: true
    },
    boxpoints: true,
    ...
}
```

Here is [Demo](https://codepen.io/jornathan/pen/ZEavzBK).

Also, please remind boxplot support feature outlier(see [Here](https://plotly.com/javascript/box-plots/#box-plot-styling-outliers)).